# I cant fix View on one place in MapView React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm beginner in React Native and I want to ask one question. Every time I press reload in Expo and reload my project my `MapView` set the image with search and `TextInput` on top start. But it always random (I place pictures for that). I don't have idea what can I do to solve this. I googled, I try to change code to absolute, I try change flex but it don't work. Please can you help me with this? [image]

Comment: please provide the code for your `<View>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you made your code available so we could understand how you set things up.

But from what you said, if by what I understood the problem is the positioning, you could try to use the absolute positioning. Here is the react documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#position

You can set absolute positioning at the top.
For example:

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 40,
    }
  })
```

In the link below, you have an example of use.
https://unbug.gitbooks.io/react-native-training/content/32_absolute_&_relative.html

I hope this helps you.

Hugs.